# What does `echo . ` (echo dot) mean?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

https://askubuntu.com/questions/250012/how-do-i-install-z-script

I was installing `z script` on Ubuntu.
I followed the second answer and it worked.

```
# Download to latest to home dir
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rupa/z/master/z.sh -O ~/z.sh
# Add to .bashrc
echo . /path/to/z.sh >> ~/.bashrc
# Add to .zshrc
echo . /path/to/z.sh >> ~/.zshrc
```

My `.bashrc` contains `. /var/jenkins_home/z.sh` w

But I could not figure out what `echo .` does in this line.

```
echo . /path/to/z.sh >> ~/.bashrc
```

Why is there a space before and after the period `.`?

Comment: `.` when used before an executable, means to source it. Read this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it). `.` and `source` are just synonymns. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25488/what-is-the-difference-between-source-and) read the difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

The dot is not syntactic in this case, it's simply a (POSIX compliant) synonym for the `source` keyword (a [bashism](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061)), which runs code within the current shell. So adding such a line to ~/.bashrc means that script will be run as part of the [startup of Bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles).